# Jenkins pipeline stages with conditions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-builder

Can I use "jenkins job builder" and create pipeline job, which I could run only specific stages in? Something like this:

```
pipeline:
    if (condition):
       stage1:
           //... 
    if (condition):
       stage2:
           //...
```

or

```
pipeline:
    stage1:
       if (condition):
           //... 
    stage2:
       if (condition):
           //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add conditions in your Jenkinsfile.
You have to define all your stages, and inside you add condition (like your second example).
You can use the `when` expression to do this :
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this, I hope this helps

```
stage ('build') {
  when {
    expression { condition() }
  }
  steps {
    sh "mvn clean package "
  }
}

stage ('build') {
  when {
    expression { condition() }
  }
  steps {
    sh "mvn clean install"
  }
}
```